# When my "grand total" is zero, the checkout button gets disabled

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, totals

I've created a promotion for of a `fixed amount of X on whole shopping cart`. The promotion code works fine in general. But when the `subtotal is less than the promotion amount, then the "Grand Total" becomes zero (which is ok)` but the "Checkout" button get's disabled.

[Cart Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rupvF.png)
PS: I've enabled "Zero Subtotal Checkout" with no luck.!

Comment: You seem to be using a custom theme, have you checked the file that displays total to see if there isn't a test that would render the button as disabled.

Comment: This may setting issue>please  goto admin>System>Configuation>Sales>Sales>Minimum order Amount> check Minimum Amount setting is enabled

Comment: @AmitBera, your solution worked for me. Thank you so much. Please write it as an answer so that I can mark mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may your Magento checkout setting issue.Please check your cart total is greater or equal to  Minimum Amount.

This may setting issue>please goto `admin>System>Configuation>Sales>Sales>Minimum order Amount> check Minimum Amount setting is enabled`